# Display content for user and for admin

Tags: laravel

I would like that normal users don't see the pictures with a status of 0 (not visible) only the visible ones (status 1) but that admins can see everything.

Is this kind of solution viable or is there something cleaner to do?
The gates/policies are not adapted for that, I don't see any other solution to my knowledge, that's why I come to you

Thanks in advance

```
public function show($name)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            $model = cache()->remember('model_show'.$name, Config::get('cache.ttl'), function() use ($name) {
                return Model::where('name', $name)->with('pictures')->first();
            });

            $pictures = $model->pictures()->latest()->paginate(18);
        } else {
            $model = cache()->remember('model_show'.$name, Config::get('cache.ttl'), function() use ($name) {
                return Model::where('name', $name)->with('visible_pictures')->first();
            });

            $pictures = $model->visible_pictures()->latest()->paginate(18);
        }

        return view('model.model')->with(['model' => $model, 'pictures' => $pictures]);
    }
```

Comment: Finally, to make the code more flexible I will add an admin dashboard rather than adding a whole overlay on the user part. However if you have any tips on my question, I'm interested :) I like to have a clean code, it will always be useful

Comment: I would still try to use Policies since this is were this type of code belongs. If you really can't use Policies, you can consider keeping the authorization logic in an Eloquent Mutator `$model->authorized_pictures` that only returns authorized pictures. You want to avoid keeping this logic in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean it up by using when function in the query itself.

```
    public function show($name)
    {
        $model = cache()->remember('model_show'.$name, Config::get('cache.ttl'), function() use ($name) {
            return Model::where('name', $name)->when( Auth::user()->isAdmin() , function ($q)
            {
                return $q->with('pictures');
            }, function ($q)
            {
                return $q->with('visible_pictures');
            })->first();
        });

        $pictures = $model->pictures()->latest()->paginate(18);
        return view('model.model')->with(['model' => $model, 'pictures' => $pictures]);
    }
```

or we could also use arrow functions

```
    public function show($name)
    {
        $model = cache()->remember('model_show'.$name, Config::get('cache.ttl'), function() use ($name) {
            return Model::where('name', $name)->when( Auth::user()->isAdmin() ,
                fn($q) => $q->with('pictures') , 
                fn($q) => $q->with('visible_pictures')
            )->first();
        });

        $pictures = $model->pictures()->latest()->paginate(18);
        return view('model.model')->with(['model' => $model, 'pictures' => $pictures]);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but I've an error with the code, not the first but the second with arrow function (i'm in php 7.4) : the error :syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'..... Edit : This is vscode problem, the page is refreshing correctly